# Duration gaps and duration gaps in terms of Months

Tags: teradata, duration

I'm trying an SQL query in Teradata to find the gaps and group the duration. I have a dataset with duration gap, I’m trying to find the gap and group them. When I use the min and max dates shows different results for long gap in terms of duration.

Duration is mentioned in YearMonth with activity info. I tried interval with rows bounding as well but shows a wrong results in case of duration gap is longer period. Could you please help me to have the expected results please?

[image]

expected output results :

[image]

Comment: Post data / results as text, not images. And show what you have tried.

Comment: i have published the mockup data due to sensitivity of the data , could you please help me about this scenario with Teradata sql

Comment: There isn't enough info above to understand the full requirements. Maybe do it in stages with nested queries / CTEs something like this: use LEAD/LAG in a CASE expression to compare "adjacent" rows and identify when there is a gap (0 = no gap, 1 = gap); then do a cumulative sum of the gap flag to tag groups. From that you can aggregate within groups to get combined start/stop ranges and separately use LEAD or LAG to identify and generate "gap" rows for each boundary between groups, then UNION ALL to get the final result. BTW - why is duration 18 months and not 24 or 25?